# Can't get Route 53 to route to elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I had it correctly working before, but I accidentally deleted the wrong hosted zone and now my website does not correctly redirect to my Elastic Beanstalk. What am I doing wrong? I bought my domain through Route 53. My elastic beanstalk link works. Any help would be appreciated. http://stubbytest-env.eba-gzmujbxr.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/
[image]

Is this the correct way to define the record?
[image]

ns-295.awsdns-36.com
ns-1954.awsdns-52.co.uk
ns-918.awsdns-50.net

Comment: That looks correct to me. did you give enough time for dns to propogate?

Comment: I think you are not still using the correct hosted zone. can you make sure the domain inside the "Registered Domains"section has the correct name server values such as `ns-1937.awsdns-50.co.uk` and the other values in the first screenshot

Comment: Hi how long do I have to wait? Last time I did it, it was running within minutes. I double checked the servers and they are the same. I have updated it to show the screenshot. Am I suppose to add any servers?

Comment: looks fine, however, try switching to old console, and then change your a record to cname if it helps, if not then switch to alias target.( this is possible only in old console)

Comment: Ahh i see i found the old console. I was reading the documentation and I did accidentally delete the hosted zone. It says that it may take up to 48 hours to restore the internet service (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/troubleshooting-domain-unavailable.html#troubleshooting-domain-unavailable-deleted-hosted-zone) I have been creating and deleting zones to get it to work but I guess all I can do is wait.